# css - make spans equal dynamic height (determined by text entered)

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to solve this with only CSS, but I am stuck.

I have the following spans that are aligned next to each other that I would like to make to equal height. The height is dynamic and is determined by the amount of text entered by the user into the description span.

Here is a visual of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="id_span_wrapper">
                <span id="id_sapn_label" style="background-color: #000; width: 20%;">Description</span>
                    <span id="id_span_description" style="background-color: #fff; width: 80%;>
                        this text can be between 1 and 5,000 characters
                    </span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular content. And what is the advantage of a single cell table (if you don't use it to center vertically)?

Comment: Ya this markup is really wrong.  You should just be using div's and classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `display: table`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
.table-row{
    display: table-row;
    height: 50px;
}
.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 15px;
}
.table-cell-left{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;    
    width: 30%;
}
.table-cell-right{
    border: 2px solid #000;    
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell table-cell-left">Description</div>
        <div class="table-cell table-cell-right">This is just one line of text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell table-cell-left">Description</div>
        <div class="table-cell table-cell-right">This is just one line of textThis is just one line of textThis is just one line of textThis is just one line of textThis is just one line of textThis is just one line of textThis is just one line of textThis is just one line of text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dimity, that is what I was looking for. I have seen your css and I understand the concept now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your table wrapper is wrong: tables must only be used for tabular content.

However, the content inside the cell seems tabular content. So you can use

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
th {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table, td, th {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <td>This is just one line of text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <td>This can be between 1 &amp; 5,000 characters, so the height can be one line or more. This can be between 1 &amp; 5,000 characters, so the height can be one line or more. This can be between 1 &amp; 5,000 characters, so the height can be one line or more. This can be between 1 &amp; 5,000 characters, so the height can be one line or more.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this rather horrible looking js: https://jsfiddle.net/hL8ryuw0/4/ , you can achieve the effect you want, without using a table and very few css lines.

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Wrap it all in a container, set the container's display to flex and align-items: stretch.

Every item inside the container will have the same size as the container, meaning the biggest item inside it will determine the size.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on tables, here is how you would do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/cos9dm55/

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

table td:first-child {
  width: 30%;
}

.background-dark {
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}


<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="background-dark">Description</td>
    <td>Short Answer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="background-dark">Description</td>
    <td>Long Answer. Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini. Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if i did not have to use tables, how would I achieve the same scenario?